# Multiple inheritance with different functions

Tags: c++

Environment: Windows 10, IDE: Code::Blocks 20.03
I have a basic question related to multiple inheritance in C++. If I have a code as shown below:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    void show() {
        cout << "Base show()..." << endl;
    }
};

class Base2
{
public:
    Base2();
    virtual ~Base2();
    void show() {
        cout << "Base2 show()..." << endl;
    }
};
void f(Base *b) {
    b->show();
}
void g(Base2 *b2) {
    b2->show();
}

class Derived : public Base, Base2
{
public:
    Derived() {}
    virtual ~Derived() {}
    void show() {
        cout << "Derived show()..." << endl;
    }
};
void h(Derived *d) {
    d->show2();
}

//driver program
int main()
{
    Base b;
    Base2 b2;
    Derived d;

    f(&b);  //Base show()...
    g(&b2); //Base2 show()...
    h(&d);  //Derived show()...

    //passing derived object
    f(&d);  //Base show()... because of static binding
    g(&d);  //error: 'Base2' is an inaccessible base of 'Derived'

    return 0;
}
```

During compilation the compiler throws 'Base2' is an inaccessible base of 'Derived' error.
If I want to access Base2's address so that it can execute the statically bind function so what extra things I need to do ?
Expected output:
As per compile time binding "Base2 show()..." as output.

Comment: Specify `Base2` as a `public` base.  By default it is `private` for classses..    So `class Derived : public Base, Base2 ...` means that `Derived` inherits publically from `Base` and privately from `Base2`.   You need to do `class Derived : public Base, public Base2`.   If you don't want to keep typing `public` do `struct Derived: Base, Base2`, since base classes of `struct`s are `public` by default.

Answer (score 0):

try this `class Derived : public Base, public Base2`

EDIT: your provided code doesn't compile, here is one that does:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    void show() {
        std::cout << "Base show()..." << std::endl;
    }
};

class Base2
{
public:
    Base2() {}
    virtual ~Base2() {}
    void show() {
        std::cout << "Base2 show()..." << std::endl;
    }
};
void f(Base* b) {
    b->show();
}
void g(Base2* b2) {
    b2->show();
}

class Derived : public Base, public Base2
{
public:
    Derived() {}
    virtual ~Derived() {}
    void show() {
        std::cout << "Derived show()..." << std::endl;
    }
};
void h(Derived* d) {
    d->show();
}

//driver program
int main()
{
    Base b;
    Base2 b2;
    Derived d;

    f(&b);  //Base show()...
    g(&b2); //Base2 show()...
    h(&d);  //Derived show()...

    //passing derived object
    f(&d);  //Base show()... because of static binding
    g(&d);  //error: 'Base2' is an inaccessible base of 'Derived'

    return 0;
}
```